# Boolean argument error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, composition

I am working on POODR's chapter 8, **Combining Objects with Composition**. However, I can't seem to make the example work:

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :parts

  def initialize(args = {})
    @size  = args[:size]
    @parts = args[:parts]
  end

  def spares
    parts.spares
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'forwardable'
class Parts
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@parts, :size, :each
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(parts)
    @parts = parts
  end

  def spares
    select { |part| part.needs_spare }
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'ostruct'
module PartsFactory
  def self.build(config, parts_class = Parts)
    parts_class.new(
      config.collect do |part_config|
        create_part(part_config)
      end
    )
  end

  def self.create_part(part_config)
    OpenStruct.new(
      name:        part_config[0],
      description: part_config[1],
      needs_spare: part_config.fetch(2, true)
    )
  end
end
```

---

When I use `road_config`:

```
road_config =
  [['chain',        '10-speed'],
   ['tire_size',    '23'],
   ['tape_color',   'red']]

road_bike =
  Bicycle.new(
    size:  'L',
    parts: PartsFactory.build(road_config)
  )

p road_bike.spares.size
```

`road_bike.spares.size` returns 3. Which is what I expected. However, when I use `mountain_config`:

```
mountain_config =
  [['chain',        '10-speed'],
   ['tire_size',    '2.1'],
   ['front_shock',  'Manitou', false],
   ['rear_shock',   'Fox']]

mountain_bike =
  Bicycle.new(
    size:  'L',
    parts: PartsFactory.build(mountain_config)
  )

p mountain_bike.spares.size
```

I was expecting to see 4, not 3. If I delete `false` from `front_shock` to let it to the default value (`true`), `mountain_bike.spares.size` returns 4.

Why `false` makes `mountain_bike.spares.size` return 3? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it doesn't need a spare - in your parts class, you are selecting the parts that need a spare:

```
def spares
  select { |part| part.needs_spare }
end
```

That code will return the parts that need spares (i.e. `needs_spare` is true). The `false` in the config for `front_shock` sets this to false. Try setting other parts' `needs_spare` value to false to see what I mean.